# Angular 5 getting ERROR in src/app/global-notifications/global-notifications.directive.spec.ts

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to angular and getting error when I run `ng test`. When I run `ng serve` then project compiles successfully. But in `ng test` I am getting error:

> ERROR in src/app/global-notifications/global-notifications.directive.spec.ts(5,23): error TS2554: Expected 6 arguments, but got 0.
>   src/app/request.service.spec.ts(3,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module './request.service'.

I uninstalled angular/cli and reinstall it, but the error is still there.

Here is the code of global-notifications.directive.spec.ts:

```
import { GlobalNotificationsDirective } from './global-notifications.directive';

describe('GlobalNotificationsDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new GlobalNotificationsDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And Here is code of request.service.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RequestService } from './request.service';

describe('RequestService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [RequestService]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([RequestService], (service: RequestService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

**Edit**
The same project is working on another windows machine and its working fine. So there is no path issue.

Can anyone help me with this issue. I am looking for solution from 1 day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that service is imported from the correct filepath?

Comment: Yes, the same project is running on another windows machine and its working fine on it.

Comment: Okay, that's an important detail that should be mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Yeah. I just updated my post. Any known issue?